# Navigation Drawer Scroll does not work when adding Gridview to the Mainactivity

Tags: android, android-activity, android-fragments

I created a Navigation Drawer Menu and added the GridView in the Layout. After adding the GridView, Navigation Drawer Menu Scroll doesn't work. Here is my main.xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>    
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
            android:id="@+id/drawerlayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#FFFFFF">

            <FrameLayout 
               android:id="@+id/mainContent"
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_height="match_parent">
            </FrameLayout>

            <ListView 
                android:background="#FFFFFF"
                android:divider="@android:color/darker_gray"
                android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
                android:dividerHeight="0.1dp"
                android:id="@+id/drawerList"
                android:layout_width="200dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="start">
             </ListView>

      </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>

    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/gridView1" 
        android:layout_width="match_parent" 
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:numColumns="2"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" /> 

    </RelativeLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    private DrawerLayout drawerlayout;
    public ListView listview;
    MyAdapter myAdapter;
    //String [] god;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle drawerListener;
    //ArrayList<com.src.hindu.aarti.Item> gridArray = new ArrayList<com.src.hindu.aarti.Item>();
//   CustomGridViewAdapter customGridAdapter;
    // GridView gridview;
     String value;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        //god = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.godess);
        myAdapter = new MyAdapter(this,generateData());
        drawerlayout = (DrawerLayout)findViewById(R.id.drawerlayout);
        listview = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.drawerList);
        //View tv = (View)findViewById(R.id.header_view);
        //listview.addHeaderView(tv,null,false);
        listview.setAdapter(myAdapter);

        drawerListener = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this,drawerlayout,R.drawable.ic_drawer,R.string.drawer_open,R.string.drawer_close){
            @Override
            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Drawer opened", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }

            @Override
            public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Drawer closed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        };
        drawerlayout.setDrawerListener(drawerListener);
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        //listview.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,god));
        listview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"select by user", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                selectedPostion(position);      
            }
        });

        /*Bitmap icon_A = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(),R.drawable.ganesha);
        Bitmap icon_Shiva = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(),R.drawable.shiva);
        Bitmap icon_human = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(),R.drawable.hanuman);
        Bitmap icon_laxmi = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(),R.drawable.laxmi);
        Bitmap icon_saraswati = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(),R.drawable.saraswati);
        Bitmap icon_vishnu = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(),R.drawable.vishnu);
        Bitmap icon_maa_durga = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(), R.drawable.maa_durga);

        gridArray.add(new com.src.hindu.aarti.Item(icon_A, "Ganesha"));
        gridArray.add(new com.src.hindu.aarti.Item(icon_Shiva, "Shiva"));
        gridArray.add(new com.src.hindu.aarti.Item(icon_human, "Hanuman"));
        gridArray.add(new com.src.hindu.aarti.Item(icon_laxmi, "Laxmi"));
        gridArray.add(new com.src.hindu.aarti.Item(icon_saraswati, "Saraswati"));
        gridArray.add(new com.src.hindu.aarti.Item(icon_vishnu, "Vishnu"));
        gridArray.add(new com.src.hindu.aarti.Item(icon_maa_durga, "Maa Durga"));

        gridview = (GridView)findViewById(R.id.gridView1);

        customGridAdapter = new com.src.hindu.aarti.CustomGridViewAdapter(this, R.layout.row_grid, gridArray);
        gridview.setAdapter(customGridAdapter);*/

    }
    public void selectedPostion(int pos)
    {
        listview.setItemChecked(pos, true);
        //setTitle(god[pos]);
    }
    public void setTitle(String title)
    {
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(title);

    }
     @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        drawerListener.syncState();

    }
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }
     @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        drawerListener.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

    }
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        if(drawerListener.onOptionsItemSelected(item))
        {
             return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
    private ArrayList<Model> generateData(){
        ArrayList<Model> models = new ArrayList<Model>();
        models.add(new Model("Audio Aarti"));
        models.add(new Model(R.drawable.ganesha,"Ganesha"));
        models.add(new Model(R.drawable.vishnu,"Lord Vishnu"));
        models.add(new Model(R.drawable.laxmi,"Laxmi Mata"));
        models.add(new Model(R.drawable.hanuman,"Lord Hanuman"));
        models.add(new Model(R.drawable.shiva,"Lord Shiva"));
        models.add(new Model(R.drawable.saraswati,"Saraswati Mata"));
        models.add(new Model(R.drawable.maa_durga,"Maa Durga"));
        models.add(new Model("Chalisha"));
        models.add(new Model(R.drawable.hanuman,"Hanuman Chalisa"));
        models.add(new Model(R.drawable.laxmi,"Laxmi Mata"));
        models.add(new Model(R.drawable.hanuman,"Lord Hanuman"));
        models.add(new Model(R.drawable.shiva,"Lord Shiva"));
        models.add(new Model(R.drawable.saraswati,"Saraswati Mata"));
        models.add(new Model(R.drawable.maa_durga,"Maa Durga"));
        return models;
    }
}
```

**MyAdapter.java**

```
    class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter
     {
     private Context context;
 // String[] godNames;
 // int [] images ={R.drawable.ganesha,R.drawable.laxmi,R.drawable.shiva,R.drawable.saraswati,R.drawable.maa_durga,R.drawable.vishnu};
   private ArrayList<Model> modelsArrayList;

   public MyAdapter(Context context,ArrayList<Model> modelsArrayList) {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
      // this.context =context;
      // godNames = context.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.godess);
        this.context = context;
        this.modelsArrayList = modelsArrayList;
}


    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        //TODO Auto-generated method stub
        /*View row = null;

        if(convertView == null)
        {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_row,null);

        }
        else 
        {
            row = convertView;

        }
        TextView titleTextView = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.textView_row);
        ImageView titleImageView = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.imageView_row);

        titleTextView.setText(godNames[position]);
        titleImageView.setImageResource(images[position]);

        return row;*/
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

            // 2. Get rowView from inflater

            View row = null;
            if(!modelsArrayList.get(position).isGroupHeader()){
                row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_row, null);
                TextView titleTextView = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.textView_row);
                ImageView titleImageView = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.imageView_row);

                titleTextView.setText(modelsArrayList.get(position).getTitle());
                titleImageView.setImageResource(modelsArrayList.get(position).getIcon());

           }
            else{

                row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.group_header_item, null);
                TextView titleView = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.header);
                titleView.setText(modelsArrayList.get(position).getTitle());
                row.setLongClickable(false);
                row.setOnClickListener(null);
                row.setOnLongClickListener(null);



        }
            return row;

    }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
           return modelsArrayList.size();
        }


        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return modelsArrayList.get(position);
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When we build a custom Navigation, navigation drawer linear layout change the view not to be front even it shown in front is call as **Z order tree** .That is the reason when we added in another component in the main.xml file  where the navigation Drawer belong it does not scroll and clickable.

so to solve the problem we should bring the navigation drawer list as front view in Activity.To do this we should add the following code when we work with Custom Navigation Drawer.

```
                listview.bringToFront();
                drawerlayout.requestLayout();
listview.setOnScrollListener(new OnScrollListener() {

            @Override
            public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                  if (scrollState == SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) {
                         listview.bringToFront();
                        drawerlayout.requestLayout();
                 }               

            }

            @Override
            public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem,
                    int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });
```

Now the Drawer List will start Scroll and OnItemClickListener will start work for each element of DrawerList........

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem where I had Linear and Relative Layouts below the Drawer Layout. I managed to solve this by defining the Linear and Relative Layouts before the Drawer Layout.

Comment: Hey @Monka Give example also to better understanding